# Can I really launch a library kernel (CUkernel) rather than an in-context kernel (CUfunction)?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

With CUDA 12.0, support has been added to loading libraries of kernels dynamically from disk or from memory: Driver API, [§ 6.12 Library Management](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__LIBRARY.html). And from these libraries, one can load "kernels" - without an associated device nor a context. Their handle is a `CUkernel`, as opposed to `CUfunction` for proper, in-context, kernels.

Now, in the [§ 6.22 execution control section](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html) of the Driver API, various launch functions are now described as taking either "a CUDA function `CUfunction` or a CUDA kernel `CUkernel`: `cuLaunchKernel`, `cuLaunchKernelEx`, `cuLaunchCooperativeKernel` and perhaps additional ones.

The thing is, that when I look at their signatures - they all still take plain old `CUfunction`'s no `CUkernel` - and there is no overloaded function which differs on the choice of this parameter.

So, what gives? Can we launch `CUKernel`'s, or can't we?

Answer (score 4):

You can cast `CUkernel` to `CUfunction` when using it with `cuLaunchKernel`, as indicated on [this part of the CUDA Driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gb8f3dc3031b40da29d5f9a7139e52e15):

> Note that the API can also be used to launch context-less kernel CUkernel by querying the handle using cuLibraryGetKernel() and then passing it to the API by casting to CUfunction. Here, the context to launch the kernel on will either be taken from the specified stream hStream or the current context in case of NULL stream.

For more information, check out [this blog post on context-independent module loading](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-context-independent-module-loading/). Thanks!